# Haskell, sort a list of Int

Tags: haskell

I need to sort a list of Ints, [Int]. However when I use sort it gives me error message:Variable not in scope: sort :: [Int] -> [a0] how do I get around this problem?

my code simplified:

```
     data Point= P Shape Int
     getInt (P _ i)=i
     sorted::[Point]->[Int]
     sorted ps= sort(map getInt ps)
```

Comment: Have you imported it from `Data.List`? Could you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 2):

If you're searching for a function of which you know (or guess) the name, but don't know where it is defined, [Hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) is your best<sup>†</sup> friend. Asked for `sort`, [it'll give](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=sort)

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
base -Data.List  
> The sort function implements a stable sorting algorithm. It is a special case of sortBy, which allows the programmer to supply their own comparison function.

sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
base -GHC.OldList  
> The sort function implements a stable sorting algorithm. It is a special case of sortBy, which allows the programmer to supply their own comparison function.

sort :: ByteString -> ByteString
bytestring -Data.ByteString.Char8  Data.ByteString  
> O(n) Sort a ByteString efficiently, using counting sort.

...
```

Well, you don't need anything about byte strings (or `Seq`s or other more advanced types), nor do you want to touch a module called `GHC.OldList` (this is some legacy stuff that may be used to quickly make old code compatible with new GHC versions); the `Data.List` version is apparently fine. So import that:

```
import Data.List (sort)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ sort [3,1,2]
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Hayoo is one of two popular Haskell search engines and works IMO better for searching by name. The alternative, [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle), is a bit more fiddly but can additionally search also *by type signature*. I recommend [the Stackage version](https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.21/hoogle).</sub>